# How to be a WP theme developer

Tags: wordpress

I want to be a wordpress theme developer.
I already know HTML,CSS,PHP,MYsql very clearly.
I know how to run a blog with wordpress.
So,what should i learn now.?Please suggest me?

Comment: I don't want to be snarky, but you are familiar with the concept of "internet search"? Here's a link to get you started: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Wordpress+Theme+tutorial

Comment: http://scriptbaker.com/common-mistakes-in-wordpress-theme-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to understand the basic structure and file higher key of any standard wordpress theme like twenty twelve . Then try to make child theme based on it. You can see this link http://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/wordpress-child-theme-tutorial .

Once you are okay with child theme development you can take approach to build wordpress theme .

If you want to build theme from a html then you can also see this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html-creating-template-files--wp-33939

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

It explains how you develop a wordpress theme from scratch. It's free to publish at theme at no cost. Take a look at the fundamentals of wordpress theme development http://line25.com/articles/15-tutorials-to-help-you-build-wordpress-themes. These arte just a bunch of tutorials to help users create modern themes since that is the key to popularity, I believe.